# Freemarker using Map values with macro

Tags: macros, maps, freemarker

I'm using a Freemarker macro for managing the content of two maps.

```
<#macro MACRO_NAME v>
       <#nested v.val, v.msg>
</#macro>
```

Fruit map is structured like this

Map("fruits" -> Map("val", Map("banana" -> "yellow, "orange" -> "orange"), "msg" -> null))

And the other map, animals, looks like this

Map("animals" -> Map("insects" -> Map("butterflies" -> Map("val" -> Map("Hasora anura" -> "blue", Hasora badra -> "yellow"), "msg" -> null))))

It is ok if val is null, because I've a check in my Freemarker code. If fruits.val is null the following code will output false, false (the correct behavior)

```
${fruits.val???c}
<@MACRO_NAME fruits; fu, fuMsg>
  ${fu???c}
</@MACRO_NAME>

${animals.insects.butterflies.val???c}
<@MACRO_NAME animals.insects.butterflies; butterflies, buMsg>
  ${butterflies???c}
</@MACRO_NAME>
```

But my Problem is that if animals.insects.butterflies.val is null, this will output false, true but it should be false, false too.

I've have no idea why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow a really weird behavior I think

the answer is: never, never name the loop var like your map key.

<@MACRO_NAME animals.insects.butterflies; bu, buMsg> instead of
<@MACRO_NAME animals.insects.butterflies; butterflies, buMsg> will work...

it was just a naming problem.

Comment: The problem occurs if you have a top-level variable in scope with the same name as the loop variable. When FM sees that the loop variable is null (missing), if falls back to the higher scope to find the variable there. This is (again) a problem caused be that for FTL null and missing is the same.